# Is it possible to add resolutions to the Virtual Screen Menu in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution

VirtualBox has an item labelled *Virtual Screen 1* under the *View* menu which lists a number of standard legacy resolutions from 640x480 to 1920x1200. Even from a Windows Guest running on a Linux Host, the resolution selection menu stops at 1920x1440, so I've been relying on the VBoxManage command to set higher resolutions. Even though I've tried to add a custom resolution using the command below, it does not appear anywhere:

> VBoxManage.exe setextradata "YourMachineName" CustomVideoMode1
> "WidthxHeightxBpp"

Changing the resolution directly works:

> VBoxManage controlvm Windows10Creative setvideomodehint 3200 1800 32

**Can one add a custom resolution to the VirtualBox menu?**

Comment: I am not sure about the VBox menu, but you should be able to install custom resolutions in the virtual machine. I suggest trying that.

Comment: Care to share how to 'install custom resolutions'? The guests in the case is Windows 10 64-bits

Comment: Go to Settings, System, Display and set the closest resolution.  Close this and then use the VBOX menu to fit the Guest to the main VBOX window.  That sets the custom resolution in VMware for me and it should work in VBOX.